# Angular JS 2 can't open in my browser in live example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

[opening angular 2 js in live example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKrsH.png)

when i try to open it using plunker it just shoing "Loading.."
 the whole time
and when i try to debug it it just show "ng not define"

any solution for this? when i try to open it in another computer it just fine..
but in my computer it's not working

Comment: Can you link plunkr?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html  
i try to open it from this angular 2 links

Comment: I have this regularly in Plunker. Comes and goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can press F12 key -> F5 to refresh page.

Comment: still error it shows "ReferenceError: ng is not defined" in app.component and main.js

Comment: Can you give link plunkr?

Comment: i open it from this link https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html there is a live example

Comment: I clicked, it working well, you can try chrome browser

Comment: yap that's the problem, just in my computer i try it using chrome, mozilla ,ie all not working but in different comp its working fine hemmm...